# 'This app is incompatible with all of your devices' on paid versions only?

Tags: android, google-play, device, incompatibility

My own paid version android apps have suddenly started reporting "This app is incompatible with all of your devices." However, the free demos which are almost identical, are still OK and show no change? I have read many posts on this subjects and have checked out all the 'usual suspects' such as country distribution.. But couldn't find an answer. I've asked for GP support, but received no reply. The apps where tested on my own phone through development and  run just fine.. The apps have been published for a good 2 years now without a problem. I have no idea where this issue has come from. I'm flummoxed!

Can anyone de-flummox me please?

The apps in question are : [Tect O Trak](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trib.app.tectotrak) and [Track and Event](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trib.app.trackandeventgps)

Comment: You didn't give us any code of what is the difference between paid version and free demos, what kind of answer do you expect? It's not like there is some kind of difference unless you make it a difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not code related. Everything was fine until recently. At the risk of alienating myself, i am not an actual coder just a developer. I developed this very small app for my hobby, and I am kind of out of my depth.

Comment: I have been working on one of the apps recently, but the other app is unchanged for nearly 2 years. and yet they have both simultaneously started displaying the compatibility message.

Comment: I have just received a (late) reply from GP support and they have asked "  "Can you please confirm if you are signed in to the Play Store using your Developer Account email address and if you are seeing the incompatibility message on the web Play Store on a PC?"    Well   I can confirm that is precisely the case. I see no issue when i view the store listings on my phone. It seems like they know something...  Hopefully i might get an answer.   :)

Comment: I have just received a rather speedy reply from gp support ( considering their lateness with the initial inquiry)   It reads as follows.  

"It looks like our engineers were looking into the incompatible devices error. The error message text is currently being worked on. The issue is that the system perceives that the owner (based on email) is attempting to buy their own app - which is against policy. But, instead of specifying a tailored message to you specifically as the owner, the system generates the incompatible error message. This error does not extend to your users."

Comment: So it would seem I just have to wait for them to put it right..  I hope someone else finds this post useful.

Answer (score 2):

Google states "Owners of the dev account are forbidden from purchasing their own apps."  This is why you see 'This app is incompatible with all of your devices' for your own paid apps.  It's normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a Google bug in Google Play's web client and is unfixable by the developer.

At this time Google is claiming, over support e-mail, that it is only happening on Developer accounts but what I am hearing from users is that the bug is wider spread than that.

This is definitely an issue that is on Google's side, we had some applications start showing this error (to users) after going a 6 months without an update or issue.